# Web scraping but not scraping changes

Tags: javascript, bash, web-scraping, curl, wget

Trying to monitor changes on this page: **at5.nl/zoek/pijp** . "pijp" is a query keyword here. It shows a list of articles with the latest on top:

[enter image description here][1]
When I scrape this page with curl or wget (example attached) I don’t see any changes in the resulting file over time or using different keywords. Examining the content of the file (obviously) there’s nothing related to the content I see in my browser. Coming across a lot of javascript. My first goal is just to see if something changes in browser output from a script. The script checks this every 5 minutes and then sends an @mail in case of changes.

As you might have guessed I am definitely no web developer. Any pointers as to how I could scrape my desired changes?
(Fairly proficient with bash)

Here's a link to the file I get with cURL:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-QzoTgbqc_m96YOx6qBh1eIBDyD5HfW_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The content is added to the page using Javascript, and isn't present in the HTML.  By looking at the Network tab in developer tools, you can find the (POST) request that is sent that gets the data - https://ditisdesupercooleappapi.at5.nl/api/search, perhaps you can make use of the data there instead of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

As @James pointed out, you could use the API-url and parse the resulting JSON to your liking. The JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) can help you out:

```
$ xidel -s \
  -d '{{"searchTerm":"pijp"}}' \
  "https://ditisdesupercooleappapi.at5.nl/api/search" \
  -e '$json/(articles)()[created gt (current-dateTime() - dateTime("1970-01-01T00:05:00Z")) div dayTimeDuration("PT1S")]'
```

"pijp" (as a value in a JSON object) is sent (POST-request) to the API-url, after which the resulting JSON is parsed in such a way that it will only return those articles that have a `created` attribute whose value (an [Epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) is only 5 minutes old.